# Is there any Callback option in GCP cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, callback, google-cloud-functions

I am looking for a way to "wake up" the cloud function when a related process is done.

To understand in-depth - these are the functions I have-

**1.** A cloud function that gets called any X time and its purpose is to call another function (function # 2).
**2.** An external provider function that requests information, (I can't edit the code, I have only the request body). The information is not received in real-time, but once it ends - it sends a callback. It should be noted that the process can take long minutes and even hours.

I want to create a process where every X time function 1 will call function 2 and as soon as the second is over it will return the information to function 1 and it will store it in DB.

**Example code for func1:**

```py
import requests

def entry_point():// func1
   response = requests.get('https://outsourceapi.com/get_info')// func2
   
   save_response_in_DB(response.json())// This will happand after getting response
```

Because I can not keep function 1 awake for so long, is there a way to "wake it up" again?
Or alternatively another solution?

Comment: I'm not sure to have caught your use case and the challenge. Can you explain differently? Or maybe with a schema? i'm lost between function 1 and 2, which are doing what,...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I edited the question and add codesnap

Comment: Can you tell to your function 2 to send a request to a specific endpoint at the end of the processing? Are you the owner of the functions 2 and can you implement custom code in it?